# A basic computation with spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, motivic-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category

Let $\mathbb{E}=\big(E_n, \sigma_n\colon T\wedge E_n\to E_{n+1}\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a $T$-spectrum, either in the topological setting (with $T=S^1$) or in the algebraic setting (with $T=\mathbb{P}^1$), and for any space $X$ let $\mathbb{E}^n(X)=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{SH}}(X,\mathbb{E}\wedge T^n)$ denote the cohomology groups it defines.

Let $\overline{\mathbb{E}}=\big(E_n, \, \bar{\sigma}_n=(n+1)\cdot \sigma_n\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denote the spectrum given by the same spaces but where the connecting morphisms are the previous ones multiplyed by the $n+1$. There is a natural morphism of spectra $\mathbb{E}\to \overline{\mathbb{E}}$ inducing a morphism of cohomologies $\mathbb{E}^n
(X)\to \overline{\mathbb{E}}^n(X)$.

My question is: **what do we know about $\overline{\mathbb{E}}^n(X)$  and the image of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ in $\overline{\mathbb{E}}^n(X)$?** it seems natural to question: **Is $\overline{\mathbb{E}} ^n(X)$ or the image equal to $\mathbb{E}^n(X)/\{\mathrm{torsion}\}$, or equal to $\mathbb{E}^n(X)/\{n!-\mathrm{torsion}\}$?** Thanks in advance

Comment: It is rather tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ than factoring out the torsion.
Cohomology group are colimits. If the first diagram is
$D=\ldots \to A_n\overset{\sigma_{n+1}}\to A_{n+1}\to \ldots$ and
$\bar{D}=\ldots \to A_n\overset{(n+1)\sigma_{n+1}}{\to} A_{n+1}\to\ldots$ is
the second, then $colim\ \bar{D}=\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} colim\ D$
is the localization.